# SQlite on iPhone READONLY

Tags: iphone, sqlite

I use the following code to only read the database....

```
NSString *databasePath = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath]  stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"lookup.db"];

    if(sqlite3_open([databasePath UTF8String], &database) == SQLITE_OK) {
```

I get the error message below...

```
Mar 30 12:13:09 unknown sandboxd[418] <Notice>: LittleApp(129) deny file-write-data /private/var/mobile/Applications/E2112718-D0AB-46D4-8914-CC65EF262C0C/LittleApp.app/lookup.db
```

Now I know that the DB is in the mainBundle and if I want read/write access then to copy it across to the users documents but I only need read access and I have also had issues with people's phone's not copying across the DB properly, there are over 700,000 users of this app and it does show up!

So I suppose the question is, how can I suppress this notice by setting the query/open to Read Only?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using the [sqlite3_open_v2](http://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/open.html) with SQLITE_OPEN_READONLY flag instead of `sqlite3_open`.

Comment: Spot on, is that function available to all iOS versions?

Comment: @Lee Armstrong: I honestly don't know. You could test its existence via `if (sqlite3_open_v2 != NULL) { ... }`, I guess.